# (weekday daytime) and (weekend daytime)

Tags: word-usage

1a) On weekends, Mary takes care of her children.

(2a) On weekdays, Jack has a part-time job.

The sentences above don't tell you whether the events happen in the daytime or nighttime. I am wondering if I can add "daytime" to the sentences, as shown below.

(1b) During the weekend daytime, Mary takes care of her children.

(1c) On weekends, Mary takes care of her children during the daytime.

(2b) During the weekday daytime, Jack has a part-time job.

(2c) On weekdays, Jack has a part-time job during the daytime.

I'm not sure if it's correct to say either "weekday daytime" and "weekend daytime".

Comment: None of those sentences is at all natural.
"On weekends, during the day, ..."
OR
"During the day on weekends, ...", and the same for "weekdays".

Comment: 'A job' is assumed to be done in the daytime unless specified that it is evening work or a night shift. Presumably Mary is responsible for the children even when they are asleep. So I don't see that you need to specify 'in the daytime'.